# Is it valid YAML to have a flow mapping (or sequence) with the closing character at the same indentation as the parent key?

Tags: yaml

As an example, consider the following YAML:

```yaml
foo: {
   "a": "b"
}
```

notice how the final '}' character is on the same indentation as the key "foo". Is this considered valid YAML?

A close reading into the [specification](https://yaml.org/spec/) as well as testing it out on the ["YPaste Interactive Parser"](http://ben-kiki.org/ypaste/) link posted on the [official YAML site](https://yaml.org/) leads me to believe that it is not valid, but most parser will accept this (it is also intuitive that this be valid).

Note: The following is definitely a valid YAML document as the final '}' has an indentation:

```
foo: {
   "a": "b"
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not valid yaml despite multiple parsers accepting it.

Running this through the perl parser YAML::PP which has an almost perfect parse score errors on this results in a parse failure. [This document](https://www.yaml.info/learn/flowstyle.html) also explicitly states that such YAML is incorrect.